# Help Proving a Function Isn't Linear

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working through Coding the Matrix by Joe Klein (http://codingthematrix.com/); a way of learning Linear Algebra via Python programming. I'm struggling with Problem 4.10.9 that asks the student to prove at least one function from a given set is not linear. Where the two (L1 & L2) properties it must honor are:

- L1: `f(a * u) == a * f(u)`
- L2: `f(u + v) == f(u) + f(v)`

`f` is a function, `a` is a scalar, `u` & `v` are 2-vectors

The function set I'm working with is from 4.9.3-6 and I've coded them here: https://github.com/orangepips/coding-the-matrix/blob/master/chapter4/example_4_9_x.py

Matrix from each function repeated here:

4.9.3 Scale x-coordinate by 2 
\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} 
4.9.4 Rotate points in 2D by 90 degrees 
\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
4.9.5 Rotate coordinates about the origin counter clockwise by theta (Θ)
\begin{bmatrix}cos(Θ)&-sin(Θ)\\sin(Θ)&cos(Θ)\end{bmatrix}
4.9.6 Translate 2 up and 1 right
\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix}

For each function the matrix above is `M` in the following equation:  `f(x) -> M * x` where `x` is a 2-vector.

The code I've written to find which is not linear is here: https://github.com/orangepips/coding-the-matrix/blob/master/chapter4/exercise_4_10_x.py#L71

It iterates through scalars (-1, 0, 1) for `a` and combinations of 2-vectors for `u` and `v` out of the same set. Sending those as arguments into the functions to test L1 and L2. I am finding all of the functions satisfy those properties despite the book telling me otherwise.

Hopefully someone is willing to look at my Python code and point me in the right direction about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Those functions should all be linear

Comment: That's what I finding when I reason through and what my code is telling me. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the actual question: "Problem 4.10.9: In at least one of the examples in Section 4.9.3, the function cannot be written as f(x) = M ∗ x. Which one? Demonstrate using a numerical example that the function does not satisfy the Properties L1 and L2 that define linear functions."

Comment: Ah yes, you are. You've tried to write each function as a matrix, and matrices are automatically linear. So, one of your expressions must have been wrong - check through them.

Comment: Translation is not a linear transformation (it doesn’t leave the origin fixed), nor can translation in the plane be expressed as multiplication by a $2\times2$ matrix.

Comment: @B.Mehta Translation is not a linear transformation.

Comment: @amd Precisely, but the matrices all represent linear transformations - and OP's issue wasn't with the code but with the matrices.

Comment: So, did you come up with all of these matrices, or were they given to you? I suspect the former.

Comment: @B.Mehta It’s not clear from the question, but it appears to me that the matrices are the OP’s creation from the *descriptions* of the functions.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they are. From OP's comment above, 'the function cannot be written as f(x) = M ∗ x'. But, OP still erroneously wrote 4.9.6 as a matrix.

Comment: Book supplies the matrices and walks through deriving them by using what I presume is the 2x2 identity matrix (e.g. [[1,0],[0,1]]. For example 4.9.6 has the following: Assume that t([x, y]) = M ∗ [x, y] for some matrix M. The image of [1, 0] is [2, 2] and the image of [0, 1] is [1, 3], so M = [[2,1],[2,3]]. In terms of do I think I understand how to evaluate, still not sure, but i have updated my code to arrive at an answer. Where I think the attention I originally paid to the matrices was a red herring.